# JQuery ajax function does work but php script is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

alright so here is my problem i have got a jquery function and a php script

jquery function:

```
function set_session(para){
     //Send Ajax request 
     var dataString = 'waarde='+ para ;
   jQuery.ajax({
    url: '../js/set_session_side.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data); // do with data e.g success message
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus.reponseText);
    }
});}
```

set_session.php:

```
<?php 
$_SESSION['side'] = $_POST['waarde'];
 ?>
```

when i run the jquery function there is a succes, but no data, and my php script is not working/ or not being triggerd, because $_SESSION['side'] is not changing.

any help would be appriciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: you should use session_start(); at the top of your php script in order to REuse the session. it just a single thing that is wrong, but there may be a little bit more

Comment: Oke noob mistake i forgot that i should also start a session in 

set_session.php because it won't run on the same page as the jquery code.

    <?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['side'] = $_POST['waarde'];
    ?>

fixed it

Comment: you need to start the session first in php.

Comment: Are you getting the data on `$_POST['waarde']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First make sure your requesting script is correct.
2. add sesstion_start() at the beginning of your set_session.php
   ( i believe your problem is    here);